# Which metadata fields Windows 10 Photo App uses while importing?

Tags: windows-10, metadata, photos, exif, windows-photo-viewer

My GoPro had a depleted battery, and its date was reset. I edited the exif "Creation Date" field. Using the file explorer properties dialog I can see that it was correctly edited, But when I try to import the photos and MP4s from a pen drive they are all imported as they were taken in 2013.

My import configuration is "By Date".

I want to know which exif metadata fields the Photo App uses to create the folders while importing JPGs and MP4s. So I would correct it and have they imported where I want.

Answer (score 0):

This solved my problem with JPG files:

```
exiftool "-FileModifyDate<EXIF:DateTimeOriginal" DIR
```

MP4 does not have the EXIF field, so I had to use this command:

```
exiftool  "-FileModifyDate<CreateDate" DIR
```